# C#. Aspose.Words Adding QR code with page number to page footer

Tags: c#, .net, qr-code, aspose, aspose.words

We are working with documents using Aspose.Words.

Using Aspose.BarCode we can add QR code to the field with some data, but we also need to add page numberand total pages number to the qr's data.

**Is there a way to define index of page where the field is placed on?**

Tried to use LayoutCollector GetStartPageIndex method, but always get Empty Stack method.

Thank you.

```
        private static void SetQrField(Field field, Document document)
        {
            var documentBuilder = new DocumentBuilder(document);
            documentBuilder.MoveToField(field, false);

            LayoutCollector collector = new LayoutCollector(document);
            int pageNumber = collector.GetStartPageIndex(field.Start); //Tried different options to get field's node
            int pagesNumberTotal = collector.Document.BuiltInDocumentProperties.Pages;

            // ...

            var barCodeBuilder = new BarCodeBuilder();
            barCodeBuilder.CodeText = value;
            barCodeBuilder.EncodeType = EncodeTypes.QR;

            documentBuilder.InsertImage(new Bitmap(barCodeBuilder.GetOnlyBarCodeImage(), new Size(100, 100)));
        }
```

Comment: Which version of Aspose.Words do you use? I tested the scenario with the latest version and LayoutCollector managed to return page number for FieldStart node.

Comment: Also in your code you use Document.BuiltInDocumentProperties.Pages property to get the number of pages in the document. The value of this property might be not updated (for example if you modified your document programmatically). To get the actual number of pages use Document.PageCount property. It is updated by Aspose.Words Layout Engine and have more accurate value.